# How does Computed work in Vue 3 script setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I'm trying to get `computed` to work in `<script setup>`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ whatever.get() }}</p>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import {computed} from "vue";

const whatever = computed({
    get() {
        console.log('check')
        return 'check?';
    }
})
</script>
```

The `console.log()` comes through but the `return` statement seems to throw an error:

```
check
Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function 
  at <Cms>
Uncaught TypeError: $setup.whatever.get is not a function
at Proxy.render (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:39550:266)
at renderComponentRoot (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:25902:44)
at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:30019:57)
at ReactiveEffect.run (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:23830:29)
at setupRenderEffect (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:30145:9)
at mountComponent (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:29928:9)
at processComponent (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:29886:17)
at patch (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:29487:21)
at render (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:30630:13)
at mount (app.js?id=d9e007128724c77a8d69ec76c6c081a0:28882:25)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In **`<template>`**:

Getter only:

- `{{ myVal }}`
- `<p v-text="myVal" />`

Getter and setter:

- `<input v-model="myVal">`

**Important:** Do ***not*** use `myVal.get()` or `myVal.set(value)`! Use:

- getting: `myVal`
- setting (assignment): `myVal = value`

---

In **`<script setup>`**:

Getter only:

```js
const someReactiveRef = ref(null)
const myVal = computed(() => someReactiveRef.value)
```

Getter & setter:

```js
const someReactiveRef = ref(null)

const myVal = computed({
  get() {
    return someReactiveRef.value
  },
  set(val) {
    someReactiveRef.value = val
  }
})
// myVal can now be used in `v-model`
```

When the reactive ref is coming from a `reactive()` object's property, you don't need the `.value` in either the setter or the getter. Example:

```js
const store = reactive({
  someProp: null
})

const myVal = computed({
  get() {
    return store.someProp
  },
  set(val) {
    store.someProp = val
  }
})
```

Remember you can always use `computed` inside `reactive`. Example:

```js
const { createApp, reactive, computed, toRefs } = Vue
createApp({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      firstName: 'John W.',
      lastName: 'Doe',

      // getter + setter
      fullName: computed({
        get() {
          return [state.firstName, state.lastName].join(' ')
        },
        set(val) {
          const [last, ...rest] = val.split(' ').reverse()
          state.firstName = rest.reverse().join(' ')
          state.lastName = last
        }
      }),

      // getter only:
      name: computed(() => state.fullName)
    })
    return toRefs(state)
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.40/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="firstName" />
  <input v-model="lastName" />
  <input v-model="fullName" />
  <pre v-text="{ firstName, lastName, fullName, name }"></pre>
</div>
```

**Important notes:**

- when passing a non-reactive reference to a `computed`, Vue will warn you (the computed wrapper is unnecessary).
- when passing it a ref which contains a cyclic dependency (e.g: a component instance) Vue will again warn you and advise on using either `shallowRef` or `markRaw`.

Comment: How to access myVal inside the script section not the template?

Comment: @Bill to access computed property value in the code, like setup function, use computed property name with `.value` appended e.g. `myVal.value`

Comment: Did you mean state.someProp instead of store.someProp?

Comment: @Shadow, you're right. I meant to name the reactive `store` (but I typically name it `state` when I'm inside a component). But for the purpose of this answer, it should called `store`. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Computed properties appear as fields.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example) This is true regardless of whether you pass in a function (as in `computed(() => /*...*/)`) or an object with a `get()` method (which is equivalent here if you don't provide a `set()` method).

Your template should simply use the name of your computed property, which here is `whatever`.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ whatever }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```