# How to access computed properties inside scrip setup?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How do you access a computed property inside `<script setup>` in vue?
I checked the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) but it does not even mention how to define computed properties inside `<script setup>`, I got that only from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71459106/2311074

So given the below code, how to access the computed property `url` inside `<script setup>`?

```
<script setup>
import {computed} from 'vue';

const url = computed(() => 'Hallo');

const printUrl = () => {
   // How to access here the computed property url?
   
   this.url // throws TypeError "Cannot read properties of undefined" 
   
   url // <- returns an object of ComputedRefImpl instead of 'Hallo'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with `url.value`, [computed](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed) returns a readonly reactive ref object.